Warning message: In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL, : NA/NaN function evaluation
I made this model:
MC.distRoad<-glmmTMB(distStation~distRoad + (1|site.id),family = Gamma (link = "log"),
data = disp.data)
I got this warning message:
In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :
NA/NaN function evaluation
In the summary everything is ok.
With DHARMa I got this result (image; where everything is ok):
So, why am I getting this warning?
PS: Its normal to have a very few data on the type of work I'm doing.
Thank you
